# update all rows in gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms

i have a gridview,two buttons(edit,save) ,what i wanna to do is :

when click edit open the gridview in edit mode for all the textboxes.

when click save takes the changes and update

(rather than edit and update row by row)

i use object data source.

Comment: What textboxes: do you mean every cell should become a text box?

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? MVC? WPF?

Comment: @Just-Name: Please update the question, and also read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: A `GridView` is a webcontrol and the question is already tagged asp.net. Not sure where the confusion is coming from as it seems pretty clear what he wants to do, just not sure why :)

Comment: @Kelsey: That was my misread (too many questions like this fail to be specific). Apologies.

Comment: i wanna to update more than record in the DB by one click(just for simplification for the end user).. this will be like when i put set of check boxes in th gridview and when the user select more than one item click Delete button at the end of selection to delete all selected items. i think this is the same idea.if u have any ideas i will be glad to hear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `GridView` is not really ment to edit all rows at once.  To do so it's actually not that straight forward.  If you want to do it though, check out the following article:

[Real World GridView: Bulk Editing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx)

I would recommend not using a `GridView` and using a `Repeater` to show your data.  Then when you want to edit, use a different page (or a panel with a different `Repeater`) to display your edit controls.  Your code will be a lot more maintainable with this solution.

You didn't explain why you need to edit all rows at once so either way one of the above solutions should work.

Comment: i wanna to update more than record in the DB by one click(just for simplification for the end user).. this will be like when i put set of check boxes in th gridview and when the user select more than one item click Delete button at the end of selection to delete all selected items. i think this is the same idea.if u have any ideas i will be glad to hear.